# What does (1 + 5%) mean

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

(I'm a software developer so excuse me)

I'm building an application for a client and one of the formulas that has been provided in the spec is `value1 = value2 * (1 + 5%)`. When I asked about it I was told that it's some kind of notation for `value1 = value2 * 0.15`.

Also, they said that `value1 = value2 * (1 + -5%)` is the same as `value1 = value2 * 0.95`.

Could someone tell me what this means? Where can I read about what is actually going on with these calculations?

Another question: How can a percentage be negative?

**edit:** I could be wrong about the first example. Client might have said 1.05 and not 0.15.

Comment: This the drama for software developers ! Some clients know too much about mathematics and arrive to ugly writing such as 1+ 5% !!

Comment: Thanks, I got your back too :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $ a\%$ means $a/100$, so $5\%=5/100=0.05$ and $1+5\%=1+0.05=1.05$ and  $1-5\%=1-0.05=0.95$. Thus value1=value2*(1+5%) is the same as value1=value2*1.05 and  value1=value2*(1+ -5%) is the same as value1=value2*0.95.

For more explanations you can read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage

Answer (score 0):

According to me, it seems for first:

value1 = value2 * 1.05

And, the second one is alright!